# Paginate custom search results with Django

Tags: python, ajax, django

i'm looking for a good way to paginate custom filter/search results in Django. Could use Ajax. I found out this: http://www.nomadjourney.com/2009/01/using-django-templates-with-jquery-ajax/ But to use this with pagination i need to have some way to store information cross view. For main view i would like to store filter and paginations info (num. of sites, current site number) and in results view i would like to only to fetch one given page. I don't want to use session data storage, because i would like to have multiply tab open in my browser with different search results.

Answer (score 1):

There are some apps like [django-pagination](https://github.com/ericflo/django-pagination/) and [django-endless-pagination](http://code.google.com/p/django-endless-pagination/) which can simplify pagination in django.

Comment: Will it allow me to pagination of custom filtered content?

Comment: Probably I don't understand what you mean by "custom filtered results". I think you can try to use those apps and see. Both of the mentioned apps are easy to install and use.

Comment: By custom filtered results i was thinking about getting data by: .objects.filter() not by .objects.all(), and filter may vary depend of users input. I hope now everything will be clear. :)

Comment: It will work even if you are using other queryset methods apart from `all()`.

Comment: Django-endless-pagination and it works, but i would like to add some filtering. My view looks like:
    @login_required(redirect_field_name='')
    def patients(request):
        template = 'parts.html'
        page_template= 'parts_results.html'
        context = {
            'parts' : Parts.objects.all(),
            'page_template' : page_template,
        }
        if request.is_ajax():
            template = page_template
        return render_to_response(...)
But i would like to have:
    'parts' : Parts.objects.filter(prod_date=year)
were year should be some variable posted by user.

Comment: Try to use whatever you want. For more info [read the docs](http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

Comment: Yes, i read it, but still don't have an idea how to past proper filter by ajax or POST from page to view.